# Start JS project with NPM

Tags: javascript, npm, ecmascript-6

I want to create vanilla JS project that uses npm packages but without bundlers like Webpack.

For example:

***index.html***:

```
<div id="app"></div>
<script src="./index.js" type="module"></script>
```

***index.js***:

```
import { sandbox } from "./sandbox.js";

const appDiv = document.getElementById('app');
appDiv.innerHTML = `<h1>JS Starter</h1>`;
sandbox.run();
```

***sandbox.js***:

```
import { from } from "rxjs";
import { map, filter, reduce } from "rxjs/operators";

export const sandbox = {
    run() {
        console.clear();
        var source = ['1', '1', 'foo', '2', '3', '5', 'bar', '8', '13'];

        from(source).pipe(
            map(num => parseInt(num)),
            filter(num => !isNaN(num)),
            reduce((acc, val) => acc + val)
        ).subscribe(num => console.log(num));
    }
}
```

***package.json***:

```
{
  "name": "jsblank",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "rxjs": "^6.5.3"
  }
}
```

**What I tried:**

1.Just open index.html:
I get CORS exception as file doesn't run on the server:

```
Access to script at 'file:///C:/Projects/jsBlank/index.js' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.
```

2.Remove "`type="module"`" from index.html:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

3.Launch static local server:

```
npm i -g http-server
http-server
```

It has access to all files except dependencies from node_modules.

**Question:** How can I create vanilla `js` project with `npm` dependencies and run it?

`Webpack` can bu used or any other bundler but I don't want it in small test project.

**P.S.** stackblitz has such starter:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-zt2q49
but how to create and run it locally?

Comment: Given how you will end up reinventing the wheel over and over again, may I ask *why*? Why not simply use webpack?

Comment: @ChrisG Because webpack is quite heavyweight , takes time for adding to project and takes time for removing as contains big number of files in dependencies.  Can you suggest some better way apart from bundlers(like Webpack) and online sandboxes?

Comment: Since you'll be using client-side modules exclusively, almost all of them are available via unpkg or other cdn platforms. So just use `http-server` and cdn scripts, and you don't even need a package.json.

Comment: @ChrisG, could you please describe it in answer, in a few different ways with some short examples? As I understand unpkg usage has difference from simple direct cdn like "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.5.3/rxjs.umd.js" not only in link text?

Comment: If a library is on npm only but suitable for in-browser usage, or has no CDN space, you can use unpkg to include just the dist/...min.js file in your page. Not really sure what I'm supposed to put in the answer, we would also have to edit your question to fit it. Don't have time for that right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It has access to all files except dependencies from node_modules.

It has access to them. You just need to make sure you specify the full path to the module (which will include mentioning the `node_modules` directory).

Web browsers are not Node.js and do not support its ability to search inside `node_modules` for modules. You have to specify the exact URL to the JS file.

Comment: But how can I do that without hardcoding all the path in imports? import { map, filter, reduce } from "rxjs/operators"; Only webpack solution? May be some other lightweight servers that understand that?

Comment: Webpack can do it. In theory you could write a web server which would search node_modules for something that matched the URL. I can't recommend a prewritten one that does that though.

Comment: And overall what is the simplest way to create small test JS project that for testing some rxjs for example? Sandboxes like stackblitz have weak intelliscence support. And playing with direct umd imports in index.html doesn't look elegant

Comment: @AlexVovchuk: If you mean loading the library from a CDN (https://rxjs.dev/guide/installation#cdn), then that would be the simplest way.

Comment: I'm not very strong in differences between imports. What should I import exactly if to use full path to node_modules? ./node_modules/rxjs/index.js for example doesn't contain what I need. Should I point to some specific file?

Comment: @Quentin I just mean that npm module system is build on CommonJS and index.js file in my dependency is based on "exports" variable. With direct link I can't use in in ES6 way (like import ... from ...) and need to import CommonJS library to use it with "exports" way. So isn't it can be used directly as you mentioned?

Comment: @AlexVovchuk: Browsers don't support CommonJS. If you don't want to use a module bundler then this is a non-starter.